# compare between dates in .net

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to compare between two dates.
From both the dates, I am fetching only date component using `ToShortDateString()`, as shown below. Now the problem is when I'm comparing the two dates. Its throwing error --

> "Operator >= can't be applied to operands of type string and string."

```
DateTime srtdate = Convert.ToDateTime(allitem["StartDate"].Text.ToString());
DateTime srtdate = Convert.ToDateTime(allitem["StartDate"].Text.ToString());

 (DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() >= srtdate.ToShortDateString())
```

I need to compare **date component only**, NOT date and time together.

Please suggest what is the alternative way. Thanks

***To JON:-***

(I went tyhrough all what you explained and understood  hopefully what the point actually you trying to make. Just to clarify more and make a last check I ll show an example.)
I have an web interface, where I give a start date and end date for a XYZ name (Note I can enter only date here, not time).

> **Start Date - 22-Feb-2012** AND **End Date - 22-Feb-2012**

Now in back end (code), if Start date and End date is same as Current date OR current date is in between start and end date, I want a ACTIVE flag set or else not. I give the condition as this:-

```
if ((DateTime.Today >= strdate.Date) && (DateTime.Today <= enddate.Date))
                    lblCondition.Text = "CHECKED";
```

Now when I debug the code,

> Both **DateTime.Today** and **strdate.Date** gives the value as 2/22/2012 12:00:00 AM.

So, Jon my question is:- Would 'today' and 'date' work as per mentioned requirement, where only date component used. I hope it would.

Thanks a lot for all your explanantion before.

Comment: Yes, using Today and Date should be okay there, *if* you're happy using the server's time zone for the date. Are you sure that's what you want though? I'd also suggest only fetching `DateTime.Today` *once* for consistency - otherwise it could change between the two checks (at midnight).

Comment: Yes Jon agree with you. I ll put the DateTime.Today in a single varaible for once and use that so on. And also I am Ok with Server's time zone, for the current context of my requirement. (as I need to compare with today's date). Anyways thanks a lot JON, for so much of clear explaination.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you converting to a string representation at all? If you only want to compare the date parts to two `DateTime` values, just use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property on each of them:

```
if (x.Date >= y.Date)
```

And the [`Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) property is equivalent to `DateTime.Now.Date`.

Both `Date` and `Today` strip off the time part, leaving a time of midnight. It's not ideal that you've still got a type which is *capable* of representing times, but that's just the way the `DateTime` API works :(

Note that you should usually *avoid* using `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.Today` in web applications unless you're *really* comfortable with it using the system default time zone as the day boundary. The user's idea of "today" may not be the same as the server's.

You should avoid using string conversions unless your goal is *really* to get a text representation.

Of course another alternative would be to use the date/time library I'm building, [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com), where you could use a `LocalDate` type - obviously that makes it clearer that you're only interested in the date and not the time.

EDIT: As the OP seems unconvinced that `Date` really *does* ignore the time component, here's an example:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Two DateTime values with different times but
        // on the same date
        DateTime early = new DateTime(2012, 2, 22, 6, 0, 0);
        DateTime late = new DateTime(2012, 2, 22, 18, 0, 0);

        Console.WriteLine(early == late); // False
        Console.WriteLine(early.Date == late.Date); // True
    }    
}
```

Comment: @ Jon -- I only want the Date part without time; and then compare betwen those two values. Thats it. hope that makes sense to you.

Comment: @ Jon -- I now got the point in my head what u r trying to make it clear to me. please check the updated post once to confirm my idea based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime.Today >= strdate.Date
```

**some thoughts**

Think at the the following example: you need to compare the following numbers 1.5 and 2.5. These are represented in .Net as decimal, double or float, but let's use decimal. The greater one is 2.5

Let's say you need to compare the integral part of these numbers (1. and 2.). You will still use the [decimal type to do the comparison.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf.aspx)

```
Math.Truncate(x) ? Math.Truncate(y) // x = 1.5, y = 2.5
```

Same as for the DateTime. `DateTime.Date` will return the "integral" part of your date as Math.Truncate returns the integral part of a "real" number, but both will base on their original type.

Comment: Adrian -- 'DateTime.Today' and 'strdate.Date', both gets the date and time vlue. I just date component in that, NOT time. I hope it makes it clear.

Comment: @Kings: No, I think you've missed the point of the `Date` property and `Today`. They both return `DateTime` values with a time of midnight - the whole point of them is to strip off the time part.

Comment: @ Jon -- ya I understand that how Date and Today property works. Thats why I used 'ToShortDateString()' to strip the time part off. It worked in that respect. But now comparing these two values throws the mentioned error.

Comment: I hope you don't call ToString again

Comment: @Kings: No, your comments show that you *don't* understand the `Date` property. Using ToShortDateString is the *wrong approach*, it's that simple. `Date` does *not* "get the date and time value" - it gets the date value *at midnight*, ignoring the time component. Your first comment to this answer is simply wrong. Have you *tried* the suggestions here and in my answer?

Comment: DateTime.Today is the same as DateTime.Now.Date. As @JonSkeet said you're going to compare two DateTime values which might be in the different dates, but both start on midnight. You don't have to "trim" the time...(Date returns a DateTime with the "time trimmed")

Comment: @ Jon - let me clearly understand your point. I'll reply back shortly to you. Thanks

Comment: @ Adrian -  I understood the point what u said in last sentence. Its like date is there, but time is same midnight for both of the values. So it ould be eventually like only Date is there with Time part trimmed. Thanks a lot Adrian FOR HAVING THE PATIENCE FOR EXPLAINING DEEPLY

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you.

```
using System;

public class Example

{

   public static void Main()

   {

      DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
      DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
      int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
      string relationship;

      if (result < 0)
         relationship = "is earlier than";
      else if (result == 0)
         relationship = "is the same time as";         
      else
         relationship = "is later than";

      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//    8/1/2009 12:00:00 AM is earlier than 8/1/2009 12:00:00 PM
```